# Error in Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: apt, synaptic

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS and, today, when I used Synaptic Package Manager I got the following error:

```
*W: El objetivo Sources (partner/source/Sources) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:93*
*W: El objetivo Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
*W: El objetivo Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
*W: El objetivo Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
W*: El objetivo Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-es_ES) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
*W: El objetivo Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
*W: El objetivo Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
*W: El objetivo Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_GB) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
*W: El objetivo Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
*W: El objetivo DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
*W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:47 y /etc/apt/sources.list:92*
*W: No se podrán ignorar los privilegios para descargar mientras no se pueda acceder a «/root/.synaptic/tmp//tmp_sh» con el usuario «_apt». - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permiso denegado)*
```

How can I fix it?

Rough translation of the errors:

```
The objective Sources/Packages/etc. (file1) is configured several times in file2 and file3

Download privileges could not be ignored while "/path/to/file" could not be accessed by user "_apt" -pkgAcquire::Run (13: Access denied)
```

Comment: The warnings are not errors, you can ignore them. And for the second error... It is apparently a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1522675

Comment: Thanks a lot for your data. But... Knowing it is a bug... What can we do, now? ???

Comment: Just wait that they solve it, and use the terminal in the meanwhile :)

Comment: You can make most programs print English messages by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free` or with super-user privileges `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX apt-get ...`.

Comment: As for the duplicate source entries: [How to fix Duplicate sources.list entry?](/q/120621/175814)

Answer (score 1):

Select another location in updates and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```